# Looking for help coding a Lowest Common Multiple function without a GCF function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I figured out how to do it with the use of a gcf function. However, I need to create an LCM function with two parameters, "x" and "y" with the use of recursion. This is what I have so far:

```
def lcm(x, y, counter=1):
    if (counter%x == 0 and counter%y == 0):
        return counter
    return lcm(x, y, counter+1)
```

I'm wondering if I could create a similar function without the use of the third parameter, "counter".

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can check that hte following does the trick

```
def lcm(x, y):
    if y > x:
        x, y = y, x
    r = x % y
    if r == 0:
        return x
    else:
        return x * lcm(y, r) // r
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! This is exactly what I was looking for. I went through it and I understand the steps the function uses to get the LCM. However, I'm not quite sure on the mathematical logic behind it. What purpose does dividing by r serve in finding the LCM?

Comment: @eukoloko Well, the easiest way is to think about it in terms of the gcd: lcm(x, y) = xy / gcd(x,y) = xy / gcd(y,r) = xy / (yr / lcm(y,r)) = x/r  lcm(y,r). Here we have used the fact the gcd(x,y) = gcd(y,r).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was fiddling around with it and was wondering if there's a way to implement the lcm function by increasing the x value by the original x each time? For example if (x, y) are (7, 5), check (14, 5), then check (21, 5), then check (28, 5), then check (35,5). 35%5 == 0, therefore return x. The issue I have with this method is that i don't know how to add the original x for each recursion.

Comment: @eukoloko this strategy would be much better suited to a for loop. If you wanted to do recursively I can't see how you could avoid carrying a third variable with you. Also note that this would be quite slow if x and y were very large, like 1000,000,000 and 1000,000,001. The other method is always fast. (It takes a few times the number of digits of the smaller number max).

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping that function in a while loop with a local variable:

```
def lcm(x, y):
    counter = 1
    while True:
        if (counter%x == 0 and counter%y == 0):
            return counter
        counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
def lcmnoparam3(x,y):
    #SORT
    if x>y:
        x,y = y,x
    a = x
    while(x%y != 0):
        x = x+a
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
def lcm(x, y):
    if x > y:
        a = x
    else:
        a = y

    while(True):
        if((a % x == 0) and (a % y == 0)):
            lcm = a
            break
        a += 1

    return lcm
```